# Observe a MutableLiveData list

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

I am using Live Data in my application and I have a view model that extends from `ViewModel`.

In my view model, I have a list that is:

```
var songs: MutableLiveData<List<Song>> = MutableLiveData<List<Song>>()
```

In a function in my view model I do this:

```
 songs.value?.find { it.id == song.id }.also {

                when (song.isFavorite) {
                    true -> song.isFavorite = false
                    false -> song.isFavorite = true
                }
            }
```

I will change a boolean in an item in `songs` and in m fragment I observe this list like below:

```
viewModel.songs.observe(this , Observer {

            Log.d(TAG , "songs changed")

        })
```

But songs will not notify after this change.

Why does this happen?

Thankyou for your answers.

Comment: this is because you are observing your list, not your list items.

Comment: if you want to update your `favorite` status on your view than you can have `favorite` variable as `MutableLiveData` and bind it with your view. view will get updated for every new value for `favorite` variable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How live data works is, when the value of the livedata changes then it will be notified for eg:

Let your data class of song:

```
data class Song(name : String?)
```

In ViewModel:

```
val songLiveData = MutableLiveData<Song?>
```

In your activity:

```
viewModel.songLiveData.observe(this , Observer {

        Log.d(TAG , "songs changed")

    })
songLiveData.value = Song(name = "Name of Song")
```

This will work.

When you call setValue of the live data than the callback comes to the observer.

```
private val songsLiveData = MutableLiveData<List<Song?>>()

init {
   songsLiveData.value = ArrayList()
}

fun editSong() {
    //change all the things in you live data
    songsLiveData.value = songsLiveData.value//this will give the callback to you observer
}
```